# How to trigger download of CRM report as pdf on click of button from html page in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Scenario is as below ,

Go to opportunity , open any opportunity , there is an option to go to html page , there is a button on html page , on click of this button "CRM-report as pdf" should be downloaded.

Can any one help me achieve this.

Comment: Does it not use SSRS?  Dynamics AX 2013 does - and I know they are working towards similar interfaces.

Comment: I created ssrs report and imported to crm , but dont know to trigger download  from HTML page

Answer (score 1):

If it's an on premise CRM, and you have access to the ReportServer, you can have a link directly to the report on the reportserver with a render format.

[Export a Report Using URL Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx)